# Question in inheriting and hiding methods & classes 

Tags: java

I have questions about inheriting(extending) methods from classes and hiding some classes and methods from the main :)

Assume that I have class A & class B. Class B has method 1. and I need to use that method(method 1) in class A, but in the same time I need to hide that class(Class B with its methods) from the main.

I mean I want to deal with method 1 only from class A(or any other additional class, let's say Class C) I don't want it to be seen in the main. I don't want to give the possibility for the main to create an instance from Class B to use method 1. I need to do that, because when I create a jar file for my classes, there are classes that have methods that I don't want them to be shown. These classes I used them only when I did create the jar file.

How I can hide these classes and methods ?? I hope my explanation is clear...

Please don't tell me to do these things, because I thought of it, and it doesn't works : :)

1) to use private for the methods that I don't want them to be shown, because I can't do that. since, it's  a separated classes not in the same class, and when I put private near the function , I can't use it at all, only it will works with the same class.

Also,

2) To put all the functions in the same class, Because I need to organize my code with classes with a separated files :)

Thanks alot Guys ....

Comment: Thank u all Guys, for ur appreciated help...

all of your solution works with me and help me alot...

Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using different packages for your classes:

Put your class containing the `main()` method into package `m`.
Then put class `A` in package `a` and make it public.
Put class `B` in package `a`, too and make it only package protected (skip the public key word).

Now you can access class `A` from your `main()`, but you can't access class `B`.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you want package protected methods. If you omit the visibility modifier (no `public`, `protected` or `private`) the method is visible for all classses in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `protected` access; these methods will be visible, callable, and overridable by subclasses, but hidden from other classes.

Comment: Thanks alot

I use the protected for the methods and I omit (public) from the class...
and it works just perfect ;)